# Visual Global TFS Annotated/History Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'd like to find a tool acting like a global annotated mode for tfs. 
I want to visually identify which parts of my projects are basically never touched, i.e. which parts are the oldest, which parts are particularly unstable.
Ideally, I'd like to have a kind of visual history to see which parts were mostly modified in the last month or so.

Hope this is clear...

thanks.

Comment: how do you identify "unstable" parts? The history dont help out?

Comment: unstable as changing really often. (# checkins/time would be fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Foundation Server has an extensive data warehouse built-in. Some of the metrics that are available are:

- Total Churn
- Lines Modified
- Lines Deleted
- Lines Added

One of the things that you can do is open these metrics in a PivotTable in Excel, then use Conditional Formatting to highlight code-churn within your project over time.

If you follow the instructions on this [TFS 2010 Code Churn Report](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfsvcs/archive/2006/12/28/orcas-workspace-mapping-improvements.aspx) blog post, then configure your PivotTable like follows:

- Columns: Days, Weeks or Months
- Rows: TFS folders
- Data: Total Churn

That should get you close to what you are after.

For more information on the cube structure, see [Analyzing Code Churn and Code Coverage Using the Code Churn and Run Coverage Perspectives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244661.aspx) on MSDN.